# Did Moody and Shacklebolt definitely lead the Order of the Phoenix after Dumbledore's death?

Tags: harry-potter

The Wiki for [The Order of the Phoenix](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Order_of_the_Phoenix) says that Alastor Moody and then Kingsley Shacklebolt led the order after Dumbledore's death. I certainly don't remember this being explicitly stated.

Is there any canon evidence of this? Was there a definite leader after Dumbledore's death?

Comment: Moody certainly seems to be in charge of the mission to move Harry from 4 Privet Drive

Comment: @Au101 - Yes, which is where I think their assumption comes from, but he seems like so much more of a 'mission leader' or captain or something, rather than an overall leader of the order. I base this on his former descriptions and history.

Comment: Moody was a mission leader however he was the only order member capable of leading the Order.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know who else could have lead The Order. The Weasleys had their family to worry about, the Hogwarts students are clearly too young. Lupin is unreliable because he becomes a werewolf each month, and both he and Nympadora were concerned with their child.

Most of the wizarding world is opposed to Voldemort, but living in abject fear of him, subservient, and not offering any active resistance (until the battle of Hogwarts). The Order is severely reduced, and hidden from all eyes. It can't exactly put out a job as in The Daily Prophet for a new resistance leader.

That just leaves Moody and Shacklebolt who could be focussed 100% on the work of the Order. So I don't see any reason to doubt this assertion.

Comment: Shacklebolt worked for the Ministry; he couldn't exactly devote 100% of time to the Order either.

Comment: Fair point, Moody seems a better choice.

Comment: Why must there be a leader?

Comment: @Oriol there's not a lot of communist undertones in Harry Potter. In my own experience organisations where nobody can have the last word tend to become counter-productive, and more involved in bickering than their declared purpose.

Comment: Actually Lupin and Tonks were pregnant only after Harry, Ron and Hermione sought refuge at Grimmauld Place. So Lupin would have been eligible when Moody died. Sure, he was married. But Tonks was also a part of the Order. So he wouldn't have faced much resistance at home. But Lupin's character does seem like the type who would rather defer leadership to someone he feels is more suited for it, than take it on himself. Which means Shacklebolt likely was the leader.

Comment: @AJFaraday not having a leader does not equal communism.

Comment: @TheGiantofLannister You may have a point there, it could also be anarchy.

Comment: I'm not convinced. I don't think there's much evidence that either is in charge, and I don't think it's unreasonable to assume that those left without Dumbledore led it democratically or led different aspects depending on their strengths. The scene at Grimmauld place in OotP even when Dumbledore was alive makes it sounds like the members had a voice and an opinion. No one reverts to "Yeah well Dumbledore said..."

Comment: @ThruGog having a leader doesn't mean that nobody else has a voice. You'd have to be in something like an army for that to be the case. Leadership is very different from absolute control.

Comment: @AJFaraday - Well yes, they had a leader at the time. And he wasn't in absolute control.